# declaring an array of more than 500,000 elements (approx.) results in a crash

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, g++, clang

g++ (MinGW) compiles this code

```
int main() {
    float test[520073];
}
```

without any errors, but when I run the executable it crashes. If I lower the number to 520072 it runs normally. When compiling with clang, the exe crashes even with a much shorter array (it crashes starting at a length somewhere between 200,000 and 300,000).

If I change `float` to `double`, the number above which it crashes gets about halved, which leads me to believe that the crash has something to do with too much memory being used. However I do not understand why the number is so drastically different between compilers, as `sizeof(float)` returns `4` on both g++ and clang.

Also, 500,000 seems like a relatively low maximum array length. With `float`s being 4 bytes in size, it would only take up 2Mb of memory.

What could cause this crash and is there any way I could make larger arrays without the program crashing?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the stack size of your program?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<double> test(520073)` or `std::unique_ptr<std::array<double,520073>> test = std::make_unique<std::array<double,520073>();` instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This works (the second suggestion was missing a ```>``` before the ```()``` at the end). Does the fact, that this works and what I tried to do doesn't, have to do with memory being allocated on the heap instead of stack?

Comment: @gearmic _"have to do with memory being allocated on the heap instead of stack?"_ Yes,  that's the reason. The stack size is (very) limited, while `std::vector<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>` (and `std::shared_ptr<T>`) allocate memory from the "heap".